# Run php script from link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, echo

I have a small php script that gets the url of the current page and echo's it. I only want that to run when a user clicks on a submit button. There are no other form item's on the page, I just figured submit would be easier to work with than a link. If a link works too I'll gladly use that. I just need the script to run on that same page and not link to an external script (because it has to get the current page's url).  Any suggestions?

I'm fine with using javascript, or a page reload.

Some things I've tried so far:

1)

```
<script type="text/javascript">function echoUrl() {
$.get("url.php");
return false;}</script><a href="#" onclick="echoUrl();">Current Page</a>
```

That one doesn't work for me because it got the url.php page's address.

2)

```
<?php if(Input::exists()) { echo: $url; } ?>
```

This doesn't do anything for me because the submit button is the only form item, therefore my exists() function returns false because there is no other input.

Comment: Its hard to understand what you want withou some code example...

Comment: http://devdocs.io/dom/window.location

Comment: In order to post a question on SO you need to provide proof that you at least tried to solve the problem by yourself - a small excerpt of code you think is causing the issue, a detailed explanation what you have tried etc.

Comment: I've added some examples, see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php 
    if($_POST["clicked"]){
        printURL();
    } 
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="clicked" value="Click Me!"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but from what I understand, you want something like this:

```
<form action="yourscript.php">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Or, without a form:

```
<a href="yourscript.php">click here</a>
```

EDIT:
Based on your comment, you want AJAX. Below is a sample of how to use AJAX. AJAX will run the script on the same page, without refreshing it.

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","myphpscript.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Then just call the function using a link. This function will display the result of the php script inside of an html element. You can change this behaviour as you see fit.

Comment: That's essentially what I'm trying to do except without linking to another php file. The script needs to run on the same page.